# javascript timing

Tags: javascript

I am trying to show a clock on a button click but and calling set timeout event to continuously show the current time. but it shoes only a single time whenever i click the button. and if if i click after some time then it also work but do not show continuously changing time.

script

```
function showTime() {

        var dat = new Date();
        var h = dat.getHours();
        var m = dat.getMinutes();
        var s = dat.getSeconds();
        var tim = h + " :" + m + ":" + s;
        document.getElementById('MainContent_Label1').innerHTML = tim;
        document.getElementById('MainContent_TextBox1').value = tim;
        var t = setTimeout(showTime(), 1000);

    }
    function Button2_onclick() {
        showTime();
    }
```

asp page

```
asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <input id="Button2" type="button" value="button" onclick="return Button2_onclick()" /><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
        onclientclick="showTime()" /><br />
    <br />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: As simple as changing the line to: `var t = setTimeout(showTime, 1000);`

Answer (score 5):

You should use `var t = setTimeout(showTime, 1000);` instead.

Comment: what is difference bw var t = setTimeout(showTime(), 1000); and var t = setTimeout(showTime, 1000)

Comment: The first argument to `setTimeout` should be a _function_, which is `showTime` in your case. `showTime()` is the **result** of the _showTime_ function invocation, which is `undefined` in your case (functions that terminate not through a `return` statement implicitly return `undefined`.)

Comment: my code worked by just doing                                        var t = setTimeout('showTime()', 1000);

Comment: @AnkushJain using 'showTime()` is an (arguably ;)) less common form of `setTimeout` with a string as the first arg. It gets **evaluated** (using `window.eval()`) after the specified period, which is equivalent to invoking the `setTimeout` function. Evaluation is slow in JavaScript (error-proneness aside - you might mistype your call string), compared to the direct invocation of a function.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var t = setTimeout("showTime()", 1000);
```

or you can use setInterval() function, for repetitive task.

Like this:

```
 <input id="Button2" type="button" value="button" onclick="return Button2_onclick()" /><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
        onclientclick="setInterval('showTime()', 1000);" />
```

Or use it in function as you like. Then you'll not need to set the timeout after every run.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with

```
var t = setTimeout("showTime()", 1000);
```